# user level permission setting in hadoop

Tags: security, hadoop, user-permissions

Since we cannot configure default permissions for any specific directory in HDFS  due to known Hadoop HDFS Bug [ HDFS-6962 ] and changing dfs.umaskmode is a system wide setting.  Is there a way we can change the umaskmode for individual users in Hadoop ?

Example:
Any directory/file created by srv-test user would have a umask of 002 results if dir/file permissions of rwxrwxr-x.

Answer (score 0):

Not that you necessarily want to add another piece of software in the mix, but Apache Ranger, http://ranger.incubator.apache.org/, which is shipped with HDP 2.2, allows HDFS policies to be set as recursive as shown on the screenshot on page 11 of http://docs.hortonworks.com/HDPDocuments/HDP2/HDP-2.2.4/Ranger_U_Guide_v224/Ranger_U_Guide_v224.pdf.

Ranger's policy checks are done differently by way of the HDFS plug-in discussed at https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/RANGER/Ranger+Installation+Guide#RangerInstallationGuide-Install/ConfigureRangerHDFSPlugin.

Comment: setting umask mode explicitly does help to provide different permission other than default umask set in property file while creating a new directory say test in hadoop , but if the newly permission set on test directory can be inherited by future incoming directories / files created under test directory then it would help solve my problem . Other way i was thinking if above scenario does not work out then whether it is possible to change umask for some users say bob and any directories / files created by bob user will have permission as per my requirement like 775 in hadoop